# Mongo DB find method confusion in Implicit AND

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am new to mongodb I have started to learn basic syntax recently. I was trying operators with find method, and I got a confusing case while trying Implicit AND.

My Collection **`mathtable`** having **400 documents** is as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4b2")  , "index" : 1   }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4b3")  , "index" : 2   }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4b4")  , "index" : 3   }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4b5")  , "index" : 4   }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4b6")  , "index" : 5   }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4b7")  , "index" : 6   }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4b8")  , "index" : 7   }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4b9")  , "index" : 8   }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4ba")  , "index" : 9   }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4bb")  , "index" : 10  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4bc")  , "index" : 11  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4bd")  , "index" : 12  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4be")  , "index" : 13  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4bf")  , "index" : 14  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4c0")  , "index" : 15  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4c1")  , "index" : 16  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4c2")  , "index" : 17  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4c3")  , "index" : 18  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4c4")  , "index" : 19  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4c5")  , "index" : 20  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4d1")  , "index" : 1   }
..
..
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540efc2bd8af78d9b0f5d4z5")  , "index" : 20 }
```

There are 400 rows in `mathtable` collection:

- Value of `index` ranges from `1 to 20`.
- For each value of `index` there are `20` entries with different _id value.

I am trying below two operations and expecting same results, considering that they are both `implicit AND` cases.

**Calculating even `index` values having a value greater than 5.**

- Using classic EXPLICIT AND ( results into 160 records ) :

  ```
   db.mathtable.count({ 
              $and: [
              { index: { $mod: [2,0] } },         
              { index: { $gt: 5 } }     
              ] 
          });
  ```
- Using variable name only once ( results into 160 records ) :

  ```
  db.mathtable.count({ 
                    index : { $mod : [2,0] ,  $gt:5 } 
                    });
  ```
- Using field name with every condition ( results into 300 records ):

  ```
  db.mathtable.find({ 
                    index : { $mod : [2,0]} , 
                    index : {$gt:5} 
                   });
  ```
- Using field name with every condition, conditions in opposite order ( results into 200 records ):

  ```
  db.mathtable.find({ 
                    index :  {$gt:5} , 
                    index : { $mod : [2,0]}
                   });
  ```

There is no mention of `implicit OR` in mongoDB documentation( or at-least I did not find a direct reference like `implicit AND` ) .

I was expecting same count of records ( `160` ) in both cases. I am unable to understand why above codes are behaving differently.

Also, **order of condition specification** results into different number of results. As per observation, only the last condition specified in find was applied, when same field was specified multiple times.  ***That is weird and incorrect.***

**NOTE:** I am using `Mongo-DB-2.6` and code is being executed on `mongo shell` that comes with the distribution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Json or an associative array or a map `does not` contain duplicate keys:

```
db.mathtable.find({ 
                  index : { $mod : [2,0]} , 
                  index : {$gt:5} 
                 });
```

The above will be considered equivalent to:

```
db.mathtable.find({ 
                  index : {$gt:5} 
                 });
```

The first condition will be overwritten,

and the below,

```
db.mathtable.find({ 
                  index :  {$gt:5} , 
                  index : { $mod : [2,0]}
                 });
```

will be equivalent to,

```
db.mathtable.find({ 
                  index : { $mod : [2,0]}
                 });
```

However in the first case,

```
db.mathtable.count({ 
            $and: [
            { index: { $mod: [2,0] } },         
            { index: { $gt: 5 } }     
            ] 
        });
```

the $and takes two json documents as input and behaves as expected.

and in the second case, count takes a single document with no duplicate keys and behaves as expected.

```
db.mathtable.count({ 
                  index : { $mod : [2,0] ,  $gt:5 } 
                  });
```

Hence the difference in the number of rows returned. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: That help a lot to understand the reason.